# How do I set an appropriate guard if a Chef resource exit fails?

Tags: chef-infra

I would like to apply a new httpd config file, and then reload it. However, I would like to run an 'apachectl configtest (httpd -t)' to confirm that all configs look good, before reloading httpd.

I have the config file being installed with the cookbook_file resource, and only installs if the httpd/conf.d directory exists on the host:

```
cookbook_file '/etc/httpd/conf.d/web.conf' do
    action :create
    source 'web.conf'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0640'
    only_if { ::Dir.exist?("/etc/httpd/conf.d/") || !::File.symlink?("/etc/httpd/conf.d/") }
notifies :action, 'resource[apache_configtest], immediate'
end
```

Before reloading the httpd service, I want to perform an apache config test to confirm that all configs are validated:

```
execute 'apache_configtest' do
    command '/usr/sbin/apachectl configtest'
    notifies :action, 'resource[httpd], immediate'
end

service 'httpd' do
    subscribes :reload, 'file[/etc/httpd/conf.d/]', :immediately
    not_if <apache_configtest exit fails or only_if it passes>
end
```

How do I set up the appropriate guard based on the exit code of a resource?

Comment: There's a good chance I might not even be using/understanding the guards correctly. If so, l wouldn't mind any input as to the correct process. To my understanding, each resource executes linearly, so wouldn't the apache_configtest resource run any how, or does it only_if run because it's stated in the cookbook_file resource?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include this comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cookbook file should notify the execute:

```
cookbook_file '/etc/httpd/conf.d/logs/web.conf' do
    mode     '0640'
    only_if  { ::Dir.exist?("/etc/httpd/conf.d/logs/") || !::File.symlink?("/etc/httpd/conf.d/logs/") }
    notifies :run, 'execute[apache_configtest]', :immediate
end
```

And execute should have `:nothing` as an action, for the same reason as the service and should call `:restart` on the service. **If configtest fails, notification will not be sent. However, config will be changed at this point**:

```
execute 'apache_configtest' do
    command  '/usr/sbin/apachectl configtest'
    action   :nothing
    notifies :restart, 'service[httpd]', :immediately
end
```

You do not need any guards for the service, you just need an action `:nothing` which makes sure service resource will not do anything until notified:

```
service "httpd" do
  action :nothing
end
```

So, to sum up. If your config changes, cookbook_file will notify configtest, if it succeeds, service will be restarted.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Setting the action to :nothing, and calling upon it was one of the answers I was looking for. You've wrapped up my question with a detailed response that has been very helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Another option used in the [apache2 cookbook](https://github.com/sous-chefs/apache2/blob/master/recipes/default.rb#L202-L207) is configuring a guard on the service resource to take no action if the configuration is wrong:

The code is as follow:

> ```
> service 'apache2' do
>   service_name apache_platform_service_name
>   supports [:start, :restart, :reload, :status]
>   action [:enable, :start]
>   only_if "#{apache_binary} -t", environment: { 'APACHE_LOG_DIR' => node['apache']['log_dir'] }, timeout: node['apache']['httpd_t_timeout']
> end
> ```

So when you notify the service for restart (for exemple), it first test the only_if guard, which here boils donwn to `apache2ctl -t`, if the command exit with non 0 then the action don't take place and the current state is preserved.

On another note, for common things like apache configuration I highly recommend using community cookbooks (search on https://supermarket.chef.io) instead of rolling your own, you'll save a bunch of time not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, in this use case scenario, the apache cookbook is not an option. However, it provided a good source of information that I completely forgot about looking into.

Comment: I'd be curious to know why it is not an option.